# Cakephp 3 Unable to mark multiple checkboxes selected

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My Edit view file has a set of checkboxes. I have managed to retrieve the selected checkbox values from the database, and want to mark these as selected in the view file.

Edit view file

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
    <?= $this->Form->label('category','Pick Categories');?>
    <?= $this->Form->select('category', $options,['multiple'=>'checkbox', 'required'=>'false', 'label'=>'Category','class'=>'col-md-12','selected'=>$catSel]); ?>
</div>
```

$options is

```
$options = ['A'=>'Val1',
            'B'=>'Val2',
            'C'=>'Val3',
            'D'=>'Val4',
            'E'=>'Val5'];
```

$catSel has been set in my controller and is returning the correct values. I checked with print_r(), shown below:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 )
```

I have also tried directly entering the selected value

```
<?= $this->Form->select('shop_category', $options,['multiple'=>'checkbox', 'required'=>'false', 'label'=>'Shop Category','class'=>'col-md-12','selected'=>[1,3]]); ?>
```

I have also tried sending in $catSel as

```
Array ( [0] => A [1] => C )
```

None of this is working. Not sure why. I haven't been able to find any solution to this anywhere, apart from the set 'selected' as array of selections. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option isn't called `selected` anymore, but `val`. Looks like [**the Cookbook**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-inputs) is a little out of date on that one, it's however shown correctly in [**the API docs**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#_select).

Also note that you *must* use the actual keys of the options that you want to be selected, ie in your case you must use the latter of your examples and pass the strings `A` and `C`.

Comment: I have sent a pull request and changed the word in the description to `value` instead of `selected`. Also added an example on how to set the keys as an array when multiple is turned on. See this PR https://github.com/cakephp/docs/pull/2521