# Does CakePHP3 suppsed to manage multiselect datas by itself?

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

I'd like to know if CakePHP3(.1) is supposed to manage multiselect values by itself when we edit an object?
I mean, check already selected options and affect modifications like for simple datas.
According to my tests (but maybe I didn't initialised it correctly) and [Cakephp 3 Unable to mark multiple checkboxes selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991589/cakephp-3-unable-to-mark-multiple-checkboxes-selected), it seems not to be the case.

```
<?= $this->Form->create($site, ['type' => 'file', 'horizontal' => true])?>
     <?= $this->Form->input('sitecategories', ['options' => $categories, 'label' => __("Catégories :"), 'placeholder' => __("Catégorie du site"), 'multiple' => true]); ?>
....
```

$site contains an array of sitecategories.

Comment: @ndm I'm going to see why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: for CakePHP's magic to work, you have to follow its [Model and database Naming Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions) when it comes to defining your models and their relationships.